# App force closes only sometimes when I get user location

Tags: android, gps, android-location

Every once in a while my app will crash when it attempts to get the user location. Unfortunetley I fo not have the error, because it has never happened when I am plugged into my computer...

I am using this to get my user location:

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

I am thinking sometimes this might be null? If so how can I fix this force close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not force closing while getting location.. its getting force closed while assigning longitude and latitude.. put an `if(location!=null)` before asigning the values

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

//location might be null so
if(location != null)
{
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

Comment: If it is null how can I get it?

Comment: If `location` is null, then it means that their device is not in a position to establish a location, either because of connectivity issues or privacy settings. Can your app work without knowing exactly where they are? Can you work off their last known location instead?

Comment: then you have to loop it out till its not null

Comment: Instead of gps you can use network location if the GPS location is null. 90% this wont be null.. this would be less accurate but this too an option as alternative

Comment: OK, so I can just pop a toast saying can't get gps signal or something.

Comment: @Mike That's definitely a better user experience than crashing the app :P

Answer (score 0):

You have no guarantee that location won't be null (there might not be a last known location), so you'll have a NullPointerException in

```
location.getLongitude()
```

Check that location != null before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Always use Try & catch block when there's a chance of Exception.You will get NullPointerException if location returns null.

```
try {

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Doing try / catch blocks is not the 'right' way to just blindly not do null checking, much more expensive than a null check.

Comment: but I agree with you I should have checked the location object if its null.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not rolling your own GPS.. Use Fused Location Provider:

Here is an example :
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html?m=1